# Angular 2 - internationalisation - Include Custom Meta Data Information?

Tags: angular, internationalization

- Is it possible to have the meta data information in the Angular2
  default tooling (i18n) ?

Example :

```html
<key id="1">
<value>login</value>
<description>This is used in login screen</description>
<length>10</length>
<height>20</height>
</key>
```

- Are there are any other Angular 2 internationalization tooling which supports  meta data information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no implementation to the Angular internal i18n tool to manipulate the meta tags, but it's planned for Angular Universal [according to ocombe](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8947#issuecomment-353364471)

you can manipulate meta tags with the [Meta service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) included in Angular 4 and write your own methods.

Add `Meta` to your `app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

add `Meta` to your contructor:

```js
constructor(private meta: Meta) {
```

**Adding meta tags:**

```js
this.meta.addTag({ name: 'test', content: 'test1' });
// or many at once:
this.meta.addTags([
  { name: 'test', content: 'test2' },
  { name: 'test', content: 'test 3' },
  { name: 'testX', content: 'test 4' },
  { name: 'testY', content: 'test 5' },
  ]);
```

**Getting meta tags:**

```js
// only gets the first occurrence if the attribute is used multiple times
console.log('tag: ' + this.meta.getTag('name=test').content);

// gets the outer html
this.meta.getTags('name="test"').forEach(value => console.log('html:', value));
// gets the content
this.meta.getTags('name="test"').forEach(value => console.log('content: ' + value.content));
// gets the object
console.log('object: ', this.meta.getTags('name="test"'));
```

**Updating meta tags:**

```js
// only updates the first occurrence!
this.meta.updateTag({name: 'test', content: 'abc'});
```

**Deleting meta tags:**

```js
// only deletes the first occurrence
this.meta.removeTag('name="test"');
// does the same as above but takes an `HTMLTagElement`instead of an attribute selector
this.meta.removeTagElement(this.meta.getTag('name=test'));
```